# HTML keep checkbox checked after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in my code, that activate input fields after getting checked. For default they are disabled, so that the user chooses, which input field to activate and so which filter to activate or not. After the submit of the form the checkbox is always disabled again. Does anybody know how to keep them activated after submit, but also make them disabled by default?

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="var input = document.getElementById('Filter');   if(this.checked){ input.disabled = false; input.focus();}else{input.disabled=true;}" />
    <span class="text-white">Filter</span>
    <input id="Filter" name="Filter" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi,
Such requirements demand for usage of a front end framework like vue/react which enables you with binding html attributes with your JavaScript model object.
And you would end up writing less code.

If that's not feasible then you may have to handleFormSubmit and set checkbox value again via JS code

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is prevent default behavior of the form and add event listener for `submit` event and do your logic there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        //Your code goes here to set checkbox state again
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Add code to enable checkbox in submit event listener.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the state of the checkboxes following a regular form submit event you need some mechanism for storing the relevant checkbox states. There are several client-side methods that you can choose from such as [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies), [local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)/[session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) Storage, [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IndexedDB) or [Web SQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) though the simplest to use is probably `localStorage`

The following has assigned a `dataset` attribute to each of the parent `DIV` elements. This `data-id` attribute could be numeric or string - the value will be used as a `key` in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) object. Externally registered event listeners for all checkboxes will add the checkbox parent id to the store which can be easily read when the page is reloaded - thus the state can be restored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <div data-id=1>
                <input type='checkbox' />
                <span class='text-white'>Filter</span>
                <input name='Filter' disabled />
            </div>
            <div data-id=2>
                <input type='checkbox' />
                <span class='text-white'>Filter</span>
                <input name='Filter' disabled />
            </div>
            <div data-id=3>
                <input type='checkbox' />
                <span class='text-white'>Filter</span>
                <input name='Filter' disabled />
            </div>
            <div data-id='geronimo'>
                <input type='checkbox' />
                <span class='text-white'>Filter</span>
                <input name='Filter' disabled />
            </div>
            
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        
        
        <script>
            const _STORE='wigwam-banana-teapot-jellyfish';  // Whatever you wish to call your storage

            document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( chk=>chk.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                /*
                    set the text field disabled state based upon
                    whether or not the checkbox is ticked.
                */
                this.parentNode.querySelector('input[name="Filter"]').disabled=!this.checked;
                
                /*
                    Add the data-id of the parent div to
                    localStorage
                */
                let json=localStorage.getItem( _STORE )!=null ? JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( _STORE ) ) : {};
                    json[ this.parentNode.dataset.id ]=this.checked;
                    
                localStorage.setItem( _STORE, JSON.stringify( json ) );
            }));
            
            
            
            //reload checkbox states on page load...
            if( localStorage.getItem( _STORE )!=null ){
                // get the stored data...
                let json=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( _STORE ) );
                
                // process each item in stored data
                Object.keys( json ).forEach( id=>{
                    if( json[ id ]==true ){
                        // if there is a matching DOM element with this data-id
                        // set the checkbox state and enable the textfield.
                        let div=document.querySelector('div[ data-id="'+id+'" ]')
                            div.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked=true;
                            div.querySelector('input[name="Filter"]').disabled=false;
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```